# Save the data with a correspoding query ID and query name

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function that retrieves data from an API and pastes it to sheet.

These are the steps:

1- User selects the fields from the HTML form. And then click on "Run it" button
2- The function retreives data from an API and paste that to sheet as per user's selection

What I want to do is when I run that function, I want to save the data with a correspoding query ID and query name. So that I can edit the saved data.

How can I achieve this?

Code.gs

```
function makeRequest(facebookAccountData) {
  
 // API Logic 
...

  const url = base + endpoint;
  console.log(url);

  const params = {

    headers: {

      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token
    }
    
  }
  
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);
  console.log(response);

  const data = JSON.parse(response);
  console.log(data);

 

   pasteDataToSheet (data);
  
}




function pasteDataToSheet (data) {

const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const headers = Object.keys(data.data[0]);
console.log(headers);
// const values = [headers, ...data.data.map(o => headers.map(h => o[h]))];

var values = data.data.map(o => headers.map(h => o[h]));
if (sheet.getLastRow() == 0) values.unshift(headers);


console.log(values);

}
```

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? Do you have a minimal, reproducible example to share? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: So far I have I have successfully retreived api data and paste that to sheet. save query that user selected with a name and ID is where I am stuck.

Comment: By "query" do you mean the endpoint or something in the parameters used when calling UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params)? Doesn't that come from the HTML form that triggers the automation?

Comment: Yes it comes from HTML form. User selects the fields and run the query..

Comment: Something like this - https://prnt.sc/16an7na @mshcruz

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `save the data with a correspoding query ID and query name`, can you provide more details about this? Maybe it would be useful to visually clarify the desired outcome. It's not clear for me, based on the image you provided.

Comment: Here it is - https://www.loom.com/share/595fbd2e856b45c1891ba086316f0aa0